# AttributeError: readonly attribute - huggingface datasets on Mac

Tags: python, macos, dataset

Just installed datasets using pip on Mac. When I do:

`import datasets`

I get this error:

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/functools.py in update_wrapper(wrapper, wrapped, assigned, updated)
     59     # Issue #17482: set __wrapped__ last so we don't inadvertently copy it
     60     # from the wrapped function when updating __dict__
---> 61     wrapper.__wrapped__ = wrapped
     62     # Return the wrapper so this can be used as a decorator via partial()
     63     return wrapper

AttributeError: readonly attribute
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem today. It seems to be a problem with python `3.10` (not resolved at the present time). I downgraded python to `3.9` and the library `datasets` now can be used normally.

Answer (score 0):

I'm one of the maintainers of the huggingface/datasets library.
We just released Datasets 1.16.1 today to fix this issue on Python 3.10

Comment: @Quinten Lhoest this is still an issue with `Python 3.10.9` and `datasets==2.10.1`

Comment: I just tried on macos and couldn't reproduce, feel free to open an issue on github though: https://github.com/huggingface/datasets

Comment: never mind me from 2 days ago...I did a fresh conda setup  on a shared system when I reported this, as it failed with a fresh install. It turns out to be some path weirdness...Python is pulling from my user-level `site-packages` folder rather than the system's `site=packages`, even for a fresh conda env and a pip-install with version. Adjusting my `sys.path` fixed this.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading the datasets package resolved my issue. Previous version `1.11.0` and the current version `2.14.4`

```
pip install datasets --upgrade
```

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading the datasets package resolved my issue. Previous version 1.14.0 and the current version 2.14.4

pip install datasets --upgrade